# Sessions not being saved

Tags: php, pdo

So i have a silly problem with my php login script. I have noticed when i try and use it and login it set the session variable on the login.php but then when i try and move page it will destroy it. So on login.php i check to see if there username and password matches the database row's and if it does match then ill set a variable which tells the site the user is logged in. I then check for the variable in side the site and if it is set i let them view the in side of the site if it is not set i kick them.

So here is my login.php

```
      <?php
  include 'functions/functions.php';
$db = mysqlconnect();?>
  <?php
error_reporting(0); 
session_start();
?><?php 
           if (isset($_POST["Submit"])) {



    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $password2 = strip_tags($password);
    $md5password = md5($password2);


    $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ? ");
    $statement->execute(array($_POST['username'],$md5password));
    $count = $statement->rowCount();

    /// If usernam and password match we carry on
    if ($count == "1")
      {

    $username23 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $thereusername = strip_tags($username23);



         $_SESSION['username'] = $thereusername ; 




         echo "You are now being logged in";



    //Test if it is a shared client
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    //Is it a proxy address
    }elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }else{
      $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }



    $result5534453465 = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET lastip='".$ip."' WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'") 
    or die(mysql_error());  

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_log (username, ip)
    VALUES ('".$_SESSION['username']."', '".$ip."')");






      echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=home.php">';    
        exit;




      }else{
        echo "Password or username is wrong";  

      }
    }
           ?>
    <form name="input" action="" method="post">
      <p>Username:</p>
      <p>
      <input type="text" name="username" id ="username">
      </p>
      <p>Password:  </p>
      <p>
        <input type="password" name="password" id = "password">
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name = "Submit">
      </p>
    </form>
```

I have tried echoing out the $_SESSION['username'] be for the user gets redirected into the site and it echos out correct so its being set correct....

So then on the in side of the site i check to see if it is being set the $_SESSION['username']

```
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly',true);
    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['last_ip']) == false){
    $_SESSION['last_ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }

    if ($_SESSION['last_ip'] !== $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']){

    session_unset();
    session_destroy();

    }

    if(empty($_SESSION['username'])){


    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=login.php">';    
    exit;


}
```

And for some reason the page is saying the username is empty... The funny thing is tho if i logout destroy the whole session and then try and login it will work....

Edit: I have just edited this bit of code

```
//Test if it is a shared client
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    //Is it a proxy address
    }elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }else{
      $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
```

To

```
//Test if it is a shared client
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){
  $_SESSION['last_ip']=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
//Is it a proxy address
}elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
  $_SESSION['last_ip']=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}else{
 $_SESSION['last_ip']=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
```

And now everything seems to work.... I am guessing the

```
 if(isset($_SESSION['last_ip']) == false){
$_SESSION['last_ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

if ($_SESSION['last_ip'] !== $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']){

session_unset();
session_destroy();

}
```

Was killing the session ?

Another edit:
I have just noticed after i checnged the above coding the login now works for firefox but not chrome the session variables are not being set in chrome after moving to a different page after login. I think maybe it is a host problem ? I am using php version 5.2 I have upgraded to 5.3 but still has the problems...

session settings in side php.in

```
ssion
Session Support     enabled
Registered save handlers    files user sqlite
Registered serializer handlers  php php_binary wddx

Directive   Local Value Master Value
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.bug_compat_42   Off Off
session.bug_compat_warn On  On
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly On  Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    no value    no value
session.entropy_length  0   0
session.gc_divisor  100 100
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.hash_bits_per_character 5   5
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   no value    no value
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    Off Off
session.use_trans_sid   0   0
```

Comment: Do you have a `session_start` on your login page?

Comment: Yes at the top with the db connect ill edit the code now to show

Comment: This kind of questions ("I have a bunch of code and it doesn't work") is called "too localized" and thus, unfortunately, not welcome on this site.

Comment: I was about to suggest `echo`ing inside the `if($_SESSION['last_ip'] !== $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])` block to see if it was being displayed every time. Glad you solved the problem though

Comment: another edit i just noticed it has only started working for firefox it does not work for chrome... The varaible is still not being set for chrome only firefox

Comment: Check out the session settings in `php.ini`

Comment: Its a shared host so i can not see the php.ini

Comment: You can find out the settings within the php.ini by creating a file with just <?php phpinfo(); ?>, and then viewing it in a browser.

Comment: What settings you need i noticed the session.save_path is set to no value

Comment: I have induced the settings in the first post :)

Answer (score 0):

Your script should not print anything before initializing the session, not even a single space or linefeed.

```
      <?php  // whitespaces at the beginning
  include 'functions/functions.php';
$db = mysqlconnect();?> // linebreak + spaces between the closing tag and the following opening tag
  <?php
error_reporting(0); 
session_start();
```

Also check your `functions.php` file. [Per php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php): "If a file is pure PHP code, it is preferable to omit the PHP closing tag at the end of the file. This prevents accidental whitespace or new lines being added after the PHP closing tag, which may cause unwanted effects because PHP will start output buffering when there is no intention from the programmer to send any output at that point in the script. "

Comment: I have now edited so that the session start comes be for the inculde but still it lets me login via firefox but nto any other broswer. My host tells me i need to set a session time out and that is why it is not work..

Answer (score -1):

At the start of the ini_set function you need to declare $_SESSION as a GLOBAL variable.

EG:

```
function ini_set() {
    GLOBAL $_SESSION ;
...
```

Comment: $_SESSION is already a superglobal. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

Comment: And ini_set is a PHP function, not a user-created function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php